# Nexus break svn plugin auth in jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, nexus

I'v got this odd error with my jenkins subversion plugin

```
Failed to authenticate: svn: E170001: OPTIONS of '*******': 403 Forbidden (http://****)
FAILED: svn: E175002: OPTIONS **** failed org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS ***** failed
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:388)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:361)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:707)
```

My credentials are correct. Jenkins and nexus are both launched with the same tomcat instance but with two differents services.
When I delete my nexus app, this error disapear. This error also vanishes if I put two tomcats instances on my server(one for Jenkins , one for Nexus). I do not undertsand why my nexus app break the Svn plugin in jenkins. Any idea ? Your input would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that somehow a library from Nexus gets onto the classpath for Jenkins and wrecks that sort of havoc.

Without knowing further details on how you installed Nexus I can however not tell.

In any case - you should NOT be using Nexus on tomcat, the WAR bundle of Nexus has been deprecated a long time ago. I strongly suggest to run Nexus from the bundle that includes Nexus and Eclipse Jetty as the application server and install it parallel to Jenkins.

Comment: Thank you ! with nexus bundle no more 403 forbidden with subversion plugin in jenkins

Comment: You should accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`403 Forbidden` error indicates that the user account does not have enough permissions to access the URL. Therefore, you should double-check the permissions for this user account.

Comment: yeah but same user same url without nexus works i'ts like with nexus jenkins plugins ( svnkit in fact) do not use credentials